# Is a partial class internally different from a regular class?

Tags: c#

Are partial classes any different from regular classes after compilation? Are there performance differences? Are there security differences? Is the generated CIL different? etc...

I couldn't find any information about this, all of the search results are spammed with when and how to use partial classes.

Comment: No.  It just allows the same class to appear in more than one cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are same according to this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#partial-types

> A type declaration can be split across multiple partial type declarations. The type declaration is constructed from its parts by following the rules in this section, whereupon it is treated as a single declaration during the remainder of the compile-time and run-time processing of the program.

Answer (score 1):

No, those are exactly same. The compiler is just joining them files together at the build time.

The perfect use case for `partial classes` is extending of the auto-generated code. As an example, try to imagine generated `DataSet` class, that has been generated from `.xsd` file.

If you wish to extend it, you can use partial class. 
Doing so won't remove your custom code when the `DataSet` is regenerated with Custom Tool.

I personally believe that splitting classes into partial classes only to reduce the sizes of files is wrong, and it's reducing readability of the code.